# How to handle NA's when averaging aggregated datasets

Tags: r, aggregate

In my study, every individual is in one dataset. It is a time series data, so every row is an equal amount of time. In my study, I have three different groups. So, I want to average all datasets that belong to one group. In the end, I want to have one dataset, every row is one hour, and the values in the cell is an average of the group at that time point. Now, the problem is that my dataset has a lot of missing values. I have two methods on how to average the values and aggregate it by hour.

This is how the dataset looks like of one individual (dataset has more rows than indicated below):

```
              DateTime       V2
1: 2018-01-01 20:38:00 2.346598
2: 2018-01-01 20:42:00       NA
3: 2018-01-01 20:46:00       NA
4: 2018-01-01 20:50:00 6.000000
5: 2018-01-01 20:54:00 5.234660
6: 2018-01-01 20:58:00 6.132660
```

I used to methods to do this.

Method one:

I first averaged every row between two datasets and then aggregate the averaged dataset by hour.

```
daxy<-bind_rows(dx,dy) %>%
  group_by(DateTime) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) #average the two datasets

daxy.1 <- melt(as.data.frame(daxy), id=c("DateTime")) #melt the data in right format
daxy.2 <- aggregate(daxy.1$value,  by=list(format(daxy.1$DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H"),variable=daxy.1$variable), 
                    FUN=mean,na.rm = TRUE) #Aggregate all values by hour and calculate the mean for every hour
```

Method two:

For every individual dataset I aggregate the dataset firs (calculate the mean for every hour) and then average those aggregated datasets.

```
dx.1 <- melt(as.data.frame(dx), id=c("DateTime"))
dx.2 <- aggregate(dx.1$value,  by=list(format(dx.1$DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H"),variable=dx.1$variable), 
                  FUN=mean,na.rm = TRUE) #Aggregate individual X by hour
dy.1 <- melt(as.data.frame(dy), id=c("DateTime"))
dy.2 <- aggregate(dy.1$value,  by=list(format(dy.1$DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d %H"),variable=dy.1$variable), 
                  FUN=mean,na.rm = TRUE) #Aggregate individual Y by hour

daxy.3 <-bind_rows(dx.2,dy.2) %>%
  group_by(variable,Group.1) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE))) #Average aggregated individuals X ad Y
```

Now I would expect that `daxy.2` and `daxy.3` have the same averaged values per hour. But this is the result:

> head(daxy.2)

```
        Group.1 variable        x
1 2018-01-01 20       V2 3.666548
2 2018-01-01 21       V2 5.543472
```

> head(daxy.3)

```
   variable    Group.1         x
1    V2    2018-01-01 20    3.732948
2    V2    2018-01-01 21    6.409164
```

I know this discrepancy is due to the missing values. If I replace all missing values by 0 then the outcome is exactly the same.

My question is which of these two methods is right. First average every individual dataset of one group and then aggregate it per hour. Or first aggregate every individual dataset per hour and then average the dataset per group?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)` where `df` is the output of `bind_rows`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited my question.

Comment: *Another way is to first aggregate...* Please post the code of this other way so we can see implementation and find why they differ due to NAs. Also, please tell which method returns correct values for you.

Comment: I think it would be better to post excerpts of your original datasets (`d11, d14, d15` etc.), rather than `daverage`. As it stands it isn't really reproducible. If information is _really_ sparse (too many NAs), it might be best to generate a few mock datasets that serve the same function as the real thing, but in less space.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I have indeed made smaller sample datasets to better visualize my problem. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely understanding the problem so here is what I have done. Please feel free to *not* consider this an answer.
First, if you want to average by hour and by group of `V2`, `V3` and `V4`, you should rbind all the dataframes you have just like you have done it. Then, try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

daverage.1 <- melt(daverage, id.vars = "DateTime")

daverage.2 <- aggregate(value ~ format(DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d H") + variable, daverage.1, 
          FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)

daverage.3 <- daverage.1 %>%
  mutate(DateHour = format(DateTime, "%Y-%m-%d H")) %>%
  group_by(DateHour, variable) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))

all.equal(as.data.frame(daverage.2), as.data.frame(daverage.3))
#[1] "Names: 1 string mismatch"
```

As you can see both methods produce equal mean values. Only one of the column names is different.

As for the different results you are getting, it seems that you are averaging first by hour. And then use this result to average by groups of `V*`. This is not at all the same thing. Use the code above and the results will be the right ones, the ones you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not exactly what I meant. I have updated my question with a bit more simplistic dataset that shows my problem in a better way.